# Translate a line in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How to translate this single line in Swift?

```
const char *cKey  = [myString cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

I can't find the char type in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty straight forward:

```
let nsString: NSString = "some string"
let cKey = nsString.cStringUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)
```